# Selenium tests in java doesn't run when my IE9 is running in background

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I have written few Selenium Test cases and running them on grid with 1 hub and 1 node both on my PC. When I run the test cases the IE9 window opens in background and If I click it and bring it in foreground all tests run. But If it remains in background some of the tests fail.
Is there a solution to run all tests in background successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions but I haven't yet found a simple one:

1. Run IE in a virtual machine (VirtualBox, VirtualPC, VMWare Player). That way, IE can open a window on a virtual desktop; it won't notice that the virtual PC itself is minimized.
2. Use a headless browser like phantomjs. The drawback here is, of course, that you won't catch IE-specific bugs that way. On the positive side, you won't be haunted by IE bugs triggered by Selenium, either.

On Linux, my solution is to run the browser in a nested X server using Xnest:

```
#!/bin/bash

XN_DISPLAY=:17

Xnest $XN_DISPLAY -geometry 1200x1000+0+0 &
sleep 2

export DISPLAY=$XN_DISPLAY

# Disable screen blanker
xset s off

mkdir -p tmp
chromedriver --port=10101 --verbose |& tee tmp/chrome.log
```